# Foreach empty ul

Tags: php, foreach

I use these few lines of code to list folders and subfolders. It works pretty well but I don't understand why I end up with :

```
<ul></ul>.
```

This is my PHP code :

```
<?php
    function listFolder($dir){
        $files = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dir));

        // prevent empty ordered elements
        if (count($files) < 1)
            return;
            echo '<ul>';
                foreach($files as $file){
                       
                    if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$file)) {
                        echo '<li><a href="view.php?m='. $dir.'/'.$file.'" class="folder">'.$file;
                        echo '</a>';
                        listFolder($dir.'/'.$file);
                        echo '</li>';
                    }
                     
                }
                echo '</ul>'; 
            }
                
        echo '<ul class="menu">';
              listFolder('mails');
              echo '</ul>';
?>
```

and the HTML result

```
<ul class="menu">
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="view.php?m=mails/2020" class="folder">2020</a>
         <ul>
            <li>
               <a href="view.php?m=mails/2020/Janvier" class="folder">Janvier</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a href="view.php?m=mails/2020/Janvier/semaine1" class="folder">semaine1</a></li>
                  <li><a href="view.php?m=mails/2020/Janvier/semaine2" class="folder">semaine2</a></li>
                  <li><a href="view.php?m=mails/2020/Janvier/semaine3" class="folder">semaine3</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="view.php?m=mails/2020/Fevrier" class="folder">Fevrier</a>
               <ul></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="view.php?m=mails/2020/Avril" class="folder">Mars</a>
               <ul></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="view.php?m=mails/2020/Avril" class="folder">Avril</a>
               <ul></ul>
            </li>
            <li>
               <a href="view.php?m=mails/2020/Mai" class="folder">Mai</a>
               <ul></ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
</ul>
```

If anyone has any idea what the problem is...

Thank you very much for the help you can give me.

Comment: Not an issue but `()` in regex is only needed for capturing or grouping. `^([^.])` is the same as `^[^.]`, but will perform unnoticeably better.

Comment: The `ul` is rendered for directories that only include files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location of `ul` is incorrect, see below

```
function listFolder($location)
{
    if (is_file($location)) {
        echo '<li> <a href="view.php?m=' . $location . '">' . basename($location) . '</a></li>';
        return;
    }

    if (!is_dir($location)) {
        return;
    }

    $dirs = scandir($location);
    foreach ($dirs as $dir) {
        if ($dir == '.' || $dir == '..') {
            continue;
        }
        $path = $location . '/' . $dir;
        if (is_file($path)) {
            echo '<li> <a href="view.php?m=' . $path . '">' . $dir . '</a></li>';
        } else if (is_dir($path)) {
            echo '<li><ul>';
                listFolder($path);
            echo '</ul></li>';
        }
    }
}
```

and to call

```
    echo '<ul class="menu">';
    listFolder('/your/path');
    echo '</ul>';
```

**Edit**: as per your comment if you only wants to list folders, I would go with `glob` method, make sure to provide path without a slash

```
function listFolder($dir, $parent){
    // $files = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', scandir($dir));
    $files = glob($dir.'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR);
 
    if (count($files) < 1)
        return;

        if(!$parent)  echo '<ul>';
            foreach($files as $file){
                if ($file == '.' || $file == '..') {
                    continue;
                }
                   
                if(is_dir($file)) {
                    echo '<li><a href="view.php?m='.$file.'" class="folder">'.basename($file);
                    echo '</a>';
                    listFolder($file,false);
                    echo '</li>';
                }
                 
            }
            if(!$parent)  echo '</ul>'; 
}
```

which you need to call

```
echo '<ul class="menu">';
  listFolder('/your/location',true);
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but your script lists the files, except I'm trying to get the list of folders.

Comment: It's perfect! Thank you very much. Just one last thing, how can I retrieve only the name of the folder?
I tried this:
`$folderName = preg_grep('/^([^.])/', $files);`

`echo '<li><a href="view.php?m='.$file.'" class="folder">'.$folderName;`

Comment: also you may encounter issue with the link in `href="view.php?m='.$file.'"` , cause it will include full path, you may want to do it like `href="view.php?m='.str_replace($dir,'',$file).'"` which will remove the main path in link...